# How to fix incompatible type error?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to write a simple program that asks you to enter a size, then it prints a line based on what you entered. The last line in the code below is giving me the error:

> Incompatible types; `int` cannot be converted to `String`

How do I get this error fixed?

```
int smallSize = 30;
int mediumSize = 35;
int largeSize = 40;
String size;

System.out.println("Please enter your size");
size = (String) System.in.read();
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? Do you know what `int` is? Do you know what a `String` is? What do you think `(String) System.in.read();` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: `System.in.read()` returns [1 byte of data](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) from the standard input stream; this is probably not what you want. You might want to look at using a `Scanner` to wrap `System.in`.

Comment: @John3136 I don't think it's a dumb question; I think it's a beginner's question. I agree that reading documentation might help, but I think it's better to point OP towards the right documentation than to call him dumb.

Comment: Geez, sorry. I don't really know where to find good documentation.

Comment: @Tom and John3136 I think that you are splitting hairs. It's just not a very good way to encourage a beginner.

Comment: OP wrote something like this "I think that `System.in.read();` reads your input": yes, it reads input, but it is very important to understand how it treats/interprets this input. For example input `1` would be returned as `49`. Btw: you're looking for `size = new Scanner(System.in).next();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong:

```
size = String.valueOf(System.in.read());
```

This will never give you the correct size, due to it returning ASCII values of the number you entered. (That's character type.)
BTW, System.in.read() returns 'int' value.

You should import

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Then create new variable from object Scanner.

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
```

After that declare different sizes and initialize those.

```
size = scn.next();
```

should produce your desired output.